# Is there a way to tell if MEF created an instance for a type I exported

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mef, prism-4

My goal is to find any of my viewmodels that are dirty and when they exit the app , I should let them notify.

I can get to an instance based on type by below code but problem is its going to create instances for all view models as I am only interested in the ones which were already created by MEF container

```
 List<Type> viewModelInterfaces = new List<Type>();
        viewModelInterfaces .Add(typeof(IAddressViewModel));
        viewModelInterfaces .Add(typeof(ICustomerNameViewModel));
        viewModelInterfaces .Add(typeof(IBudgetSummaryViewModel));

        foreach (var appInterface in viewModelInterfaces )
        {
            var obj = Container.GetExports(appInterface, ull,appInterface.FullName).FirstOrDefault();
            if (obj != null)
            {
                var viewModel = obj.Value as IViewModelBase;
                if (viewModel != null)
                {
                    if (viewModel.IsDirty)
                    {
                        Show Dialog
                    }
                }
             }
         }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

MEF doesn't keep track of all of its created parts, so there is no such functionality built in MEF. For example, once created, the container isn't aware of any `NonShared` parts (unless the parts are `IDisposable`). [You can see here](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Parts%20Lifetime) under "Container and parts references" exactly which type of parts MEF keeps reference to.

Either way, you have other ways to achieve what you want. Since you've tagged your question [prism](/questions/tagged/prism), you could simply use `IEventAggregator` to publish an event which all viewmodels will subscribe to and perform their logic.

Alternatively, you could have each viewmodel's constructor add itself to a list of "dirty viewmodels" (this list can be held by another object), and then access this list when the application closes.